# USB Drive - The device can perform faster

Tags: windows, usb

When ever I plugin my Pen Drive it shows the device can perform faster. 
What does it mean?

If I plugin to the USB port near by will it transfer data at faster rate

Answer (score 1):

This question has nothing to do with this site, but its funny so I will try an answer. I think you are plugging your pen drive into a USB port that is only rated for something like USB1. Such as a port only meant for an input device like a mouse.

Windows is telling you the connection is not high speed.

[Universal Serial Bus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Serial_Bus#USB_1.0)

> USB 1.0: Released in January 1996. Specified data rates of 1.5 Mbit/s
>   (Low-Bandwidth) and 12 Mbit/s (Full-Bandwidth).
>   USB 1.1: Released in August 1998.
>   Fixed problems identified in 1.0, mostly relating to hubs. Earliest revision to be widely > adopted.

Basically regardless of the speed of the pen drive, windows is saying that the port is of a lower spec and not offering you max speed.

Comment: Few such devices actually made it to market?? There are tons of USB 1 products on the market.  Even seemingly serious things like audio interfaces.  I can't believe you would disgrace this question with such misinformation.

Comment: @japreiss: Hey I didn't write it. Mr Wikipedia did. I am just pointing out the data rate. :-) I removed the extra part to just emphasis the data rate. Also, don't lecture me about disgracing this question. Its not even appropriate for this site

Comment: USB 1.0 wasn't that used, however, USB 1.1 was widely used.

Comment: @MattSieker: Inserted the extra bit about 1.1

Answer (score 1):

Pen drives are normally rated USB 2.0 , if you connect it to a port of USB 1.0 then you get this error.
Also applicable if pen drive is USB 3.0 and port is USB 2.0.

Sometimes i get this error if there is a loose connection in the pen drive. Also try formatting it.

Comment: Note also that you will get this message even if your computer doesn't have any faster USB ports.